# How to split a string in Groovy?

Tags: regex, string, groovy, split, regex-group

I have a groovy script that you can find in this [link](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5162826498834432).

```
String str = '# hosts.inventory [vpc] vpc ec2  [ec2] vpc ec2  [project:children] vpc ec2  [author]   [publisher]   [dispatcher] '
str.split((/^\[author\]$/))
for( String values : str )     
println(values);
```

I would like to split my string into two parts:

1. Everything before `[author]` ie `# hosts.inventory [vpc] vpc ec2  [ec2] vpc ec2  [project:children] vpc ec2`
2. Everything after `[author]` ie `[publisher]   [dispatcher]`

My regex doesn't seem to work. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might simply work:

```
String str = '# hosts.inventory [vpc] vpc ec2  [ec2] vpc ec2  [project:children] vpc ec2  [author]   [publisher]   [dispatcher] '
values = str.split((/(\[author\])/))
println(values);
```

#### [Groovy](https://ideone.com/oYc3rN)

---

Or I'm guessing that the expression you might be looking for would be similar to:

```
(.+)(\[author\])(.+)
```

Where there are three capturing groups, two for before and after `[author]`:

```
(.+)
```

and one for the author:

```
(\[author\])
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wfx7Yy/1)